# How do I download the app I created to a folder on my desktop so that I can set the path and then deploy?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have set up an application at https://appengine.google.com/
I have downloaded and installed Python 2.7
I have downloaded and installed Google App Engine Laucher

I need to 'Add existing Application'

How do I download the app I created in step one above to a folder on my desktop so that I can set the path and then deploy?

Answer (score 0):

You can download an app using `appcfg.py` (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Source_Code)):

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>
```

But, if you haven't deployed your app yet - you should [create](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) it first and [upload](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading).

Hope that helps.